# Missing level achievement cards for levels 1 and 2

Tags: achievements, botanicula

I've done everything I can find to do in levels 1 (Three Feathers) and 2 (Five Keys), and I've checked all the walkthroughs.

Supposedly you should get a Feather card and a Key card when you finish these levels, but I don't. I do however get the Three Babies card when I finish that level.

In Level 1, I collected 10 cards BEFORE getting Branbora, if that helps.

Am I misinformed, or is there something more to do? (Where can I find a COMPLETE list?)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Finally, I've found a walkthrough that contains accurate and precise information on all 123 cards: http://jayisgames.com/archives/2012/04/botanicula.php#prettyPhoto

Click on the link and scroll down to see the walkthrough. What I found most useful is the complete set of images for all 123 cards. They are not named, so the images themselves are handy but I can't place them here (thus the link). It is useful for getting all three gifts at the end of the game.

Other walkthroughs give Czech names to the cards, but do not present a complete list. One walkthrough even mentions a Feathers card and a Keys card, but no such cards exist.

COMPLETE LIST OF CARDS

**Three Feathers: 11 cards**
Hiding spider (Balonek);
Red flying bug (Bzukavec);
Green falling bug (Soukac);
Shell kid (Ulita);
Mayfly (Jepice);
Tall pods;
Green worm (Strasilka);
Moth bug;
Undead pair;
Flowering twigs;
Flying potato creature (Brambora).

**Five Keys: 18 cards**
Magic mushrooms;
Snail;
White cell;
Singing birds;
Grampa #1;
Woodpecker;
Tiny leaf bug (Brouk);
Fat beetles (Parazit);
Musical creature (Orchestrion);
Dog creature;
Spiky creatures;
Little pink nut-man (Tykvovec);
Hoppers (Hopik);
Big-nosed green ball guy (Nosal);
Stick insect ;
White fly;
Bee;
Spiky big-head zombie.

**Magic Lamp: 6 cards**
Genie (Dzin);
Musical caterpillars;
Santa;
Moon;
Ferris wheel carney;
Black spider (Zlo A).

**Three Lost Chestnuts: 21 cards + upgrade**
Headless bug;
Black spider with eye;
Hungry caterpillar;
Walking thread (Pidalka);
Hungry leaf (Zrout);
Singing frogs;
Crabby;
Otter creature (Svolavac);
Fish-rider;
Scissor crab;
Tree squirrel (Skakavec);
Leafsucker bug;
Snail engine;
Hanging bat;
Mean spider;
Sheep;
Long-winged fly (Jepice 2);
Stretchy bug;
Angry beetle;
Guinea pigs;
Chestnut family;
(Grampa #2).

**Fourteen Chickens: 25 cards**
Bee hive;
Meditating chestnut;
Created frog (Zaba);
Created snail (Snek);
Sleeping chestnuts;
Scientist chestnut;
Snow chestnut;
Snowman;
Penguin (Tucnak);
Ballplaying chestnut;
Fat sleeping chestnut;
Shadow pets (Skritci);
Grumpy sleeper;
Toast creature;
Closet moth (Mura);
Jack-in-the-box (Krabicka);
Walnut herd;
Cap Stork;
Priestess chestnut;
Ant;
Ant larva;
Shaman chestnut;
Undead daddy chestnut;
Cuckoo (Kukacka);
Flying lightbulb (Zarovka).

**Flying Ship: 3 cards**
Chicken;
Red spider (Zlo B);
Chestnut town (Mesto).

**Four Elements: 32 cards + upgrade**
Grazing worms (Krava);
Chameleon;
Sponge sheep;
Running creatures;
Theater (Loutky);
Devourer;
Turtle (Zelva);
Hornblower;
Toothy black creature;
Planets (Vesmir);
Glowworm;
Suspended lamps;
Puffy lamps;
Baby (Nosatec);
Stag (Jelen);
Black/Green worm;
Rocking fungi (Hlavouni);
Circus;
Bouncy hedgehogs (Kedlubny);
Yellow submarine;
Black swimmer;
White slug;
Rock crabs;
Shining lamp jelly;
Glowing tentacle jelly;
Peanut creature (Burak);
Ladybug race (Zavod);
Black leaf;
Eyeless creature (Hrouda);
Daredevil (Krotitel);
Devourer tamer;
Templemaster;
(Grampa#3).

**"Heart of Darkness": 2 cards**
Four Discs;
Red Organ (Zlo C).

**Five Spheres: 5 cards**
Black sealilies;
Black gobbler;
Black leech;
Red monster;
Black beaks.

Comment: Please don't just link to somewhere else.  Summarize the information here.  That way, if the site goes down, your answer is still good.  Besides, that saves people a click.

Comment: Summarize an entire walkthrough? r u serious? :D

Here's a little more info. The link I gave provides a complete list of cards, per level, with images. That's what I needed, and I'm pretty sure others will find it useful, especially since it contains none of the errors other, less complete walkthroughs have (and to which I alluded in my question but are not worth repeating here).

Also, for anyone who wonders, collecting all 123 cards gives the same result (3 gifts) as collecting fewer cards does (but I don't know the whole schedule).

Comment: The point is that we don't just want links to another site here.  Think about it; if the site goes down, your answer is no longer valid.  We don't want that.

Comment: Yes, I understand that. But it's the best way to present the information, at least until I have time to assemble the entire 123-card list.

Comment: @Alveric There is a difference between posting an answer and sending someone somewhere else for the answer.  We want to be the ones providing the information, not simply directing people to it. The site you link to has a very well organized list of links for all the cards.  That's the kind of thing we want here. You could easily make the same kind of list for the levels you are asking about.

Comment: No, Origami, I could not "easily" do that, as I have now explained in my answer.

Comment: As a further note, the image sets at the link are explicitly copyrighted. I could copy and post them, but that would violate the copyright. Linking does not violate the copyright. Hope that helps.